# Why does the group of some file show number (looks like ID), not an alphabet string?

Tags: ls, opensuse

Normally as 'ls -al', the files always show like:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner_name group_name size time file_name
```

But some of my files show:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner_name 'number' size time file_name
```

And the 'number' does not exist in /etc/group

What does the 'number' mean? and how to fix it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number is the group ID (`gid`). Groups and Users in a *nix system **are** numerical IDs (`uid` and `gid`). In a file system, the owning user and group will only ever be stored by its ID.

To display this, the user database is queried. With a modern *nix system, this could be anything, e.g. an LDAP directory, but the classic format is using the files `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`. If you see an ID instead of a name, it means your system couldn't find the entry in the user/group database. With a remote LDAP directory, this happens e.g. when the network is down. If you just use a traditional `/etc/group` file, this only happens when there is no entry.

Either the group was deleted or somebody changed the group of the file using a (non-existing) ID instead of a name or the file was copied from another system having this group and preserving the IDs while copying.

How to fix it depends on what you want. You can just `chgrp` the file to an existing group. Or you can create a group with this ID.

Answer (score -2):

The numbers will be the group id's as opposed to the group name. To display group id's without group names, you can use ls -aln.

If a number shows amongst the names this is normally an issue with group name resolution i.e. if a group of files have been downloaded from an outside source and the group id's/names are "foreign" and therefore not understood by the local system.